# OpenCL reuse cl_kernel with different DEFINE ( -D )

Tags: c++, oop, opencl

My goal is to reduce calling overhead when I call cl_kernel
I started by creating functor class called *clfunctor*

The class consists of constructor with 'kernel sourcecode', 'main function name' and compile 'options' as parameters
      then the constructor will call *set_kernel_code(...)* to compile and build the code with those parameters. finally will get '*mykernel*' as the output of the '*set_kernel_code*' function

```
class clfunctor 
{
      // comile sourcecode to cl_kernel
      void set_kernel_code(const std::string& sourcecode, const std::string& 
                           program_name, const std::string& options="")
      { 
              char* kernel_source = new char[ sourcecode.size() + 1 ];
              std::copy( sourcecode.begin(), sourcecode.end(), kernel_source 
              );
              kernel_source[ sourcecode.size() ] = '\0'; // opencl need \0 to end kernel_code

              cl_program program;

              program = clCreateProgramWithSource( myclcontext, 1, (const char **)&kernel_source, NULL, &err);
              if( err != 0 ) echo_error( cl_error_string(err) ); // if error here.. call cl_init() ???

              //build program from opencl device
              clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device[iplatform][idevice], options.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
              if( err != 0 ) echo_error( cl_error_string(err) );

              // no have kernel
              mykernel = clCreateKernel( program, program_name.c_str(), &err );
              const size_t LOG_SIZ = 2040;


              clReleaseProgram( program );
              delete kernel_source;
       }





public:

cl_kernel           mykernel;
std::vector<size_t> local_nd;
std::vector<size_t> global_nd;



clfunctor(const std::string& sourcecode, const std::string& program_name, const std::string& options)
{
    set_kernel_code( sourcecode, program_name, options );
}




void operator()() const
{
    cl_int err;


    //-----------------------------------
    //        create GPU queue
    //----------------------------------
    cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue( myclcontext, device[iplatform][idevice], 0, &err);
    if( err != 0 ) echo_error( cl_error_string(err) );



    cl_uint work_dim = local_nd.size(); // ND dimension ( N )
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( queue, kernel, work_dim, NULL, global_nd.data(), local_nd.data(), 0, NULL, NULL);
    if( err != 0 ) echo_error( cl_error_string(err) );
    clFinish( queue );




    clReleaseCommandQueue( queue );
}


virtual ~clfunctor()
{
    // relase kernel with object is destroyed
    clReleaseKernel( mykernel );
}

};
```

and I have a sample cl file 'nothing.cl 'is

```
kernel void nothing()
{
    printf("[ echo ]: %d\n", MYID  );
}
```

after that I create this functor object by

```
clfunctor0 hello( file2code("nothing.cl"), "nothing", "-DMYID=100");
hello.local_nd  = {1,1,1};
hello.global_nd = {1,1,1};
hello();   // print 100


clfunctor0 hello2( file2code("nothing.cl"), "nothing", "-DMYID=123");
hello2.local_nd  = {1,1,1};
hello2.global_nd = {1,1,1};
hello2(); // print 123


hello();  // THIS IS WRONG I expect it to print 100 but it print 123
```

as the code above, you can see I create two objects. one is 'hello' and another is 'hello2' both objects share the same code from 'nothing.cl' but differ in DEFINE (-D) compilation. 'hello' uses **-DMYID=100** ( MYID = 100 ) but hello2 uses **-DMYID=123** ( MYID = 123 )

I expect those objects hold different mykernel since the compilation options are different. First I call *hello()* I print correctly  '100'

then I call *hello2()* it also print correctly '123'

However when I call hello() again It instead of print '100' 
it print the parameter from hello2 which is 123

How could I make the kernel for each object differently with only -D(DEFINE) compilation parameter. Or I did something wrong or misunderstand about opencl kernel.

Comment: Can you move `cl_program` into `clfunctor` object, and call `clReleaseProgram` only in `~clfunctor()`?

I'm not sure what happens if you release a program, and then use a kernel from this program.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Yep I tested it but the result is same. ;(

Comment: `set_kernel_code setting` is setting `kernel` and `operator()` is using `kernel` to execute, but the member variable is called `*my*kernel`. If this isn't a copy/paste error in the StackOverflow question, you maybe writing a global variable called `kernel`, and not the member.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for pointing out. my typo. It should name mykernel. I changed the variable name a bit before posted in StackOverflow. I will fix it

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid caching happen. Compiler generates binary with 123 inside and simply reused. 
create on-fly cl file with random name and u will be always with correct value. Or better don't use flags but just pass argument to kernel

Comment: I pass arguments instead of using flag -D. It works!. I think same as you the problem about caching something. If I reuse the same code with different -D flag, the problem will happen but if I use other cl codes, everything is fine.

Comment: Caching mechanism should take compiler options into account, otherwise it is a bug in the opencl driver.